# Create a timer that you can edit android(Java)

Tags: java, android, xml, timer

I build a simple timer app and i want to make it editable so the user can chooose Hour,minutes,sec. I tryed using EditText but it's not really working it's not really let me change anything.
this is the code:

xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_stopwatch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.adir.stopwatch.StopwatchActivity"
    android:background="#000000"    
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickReset"
        android:text="@string/reset"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/stop_button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="92sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickStart"
android:text="@string/start"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickStop"
        android:text="@string/stop"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_button"></Button>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
   public class StopwatchActivity extends Activity {
    private int seconds=0;
    private boolean running;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
        runTimer();
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {    
        running = true;    }

    public void onClickStop(View view) {
        running = false;  
    }

    public void onClickReset(View view) {
        running = false;
        seconds = 0;    
    }

    private void runTimer() {
        final EditText timeView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int hours=seconds/3600;
                int minutes=(seconds%3600)/60;
                int secs=seconds%60;
                String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, secs);
                timeView.setText(time);
                if (running) {
                    seconds--;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });  
    }  
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Use an EditText or TimePicker

Comment: @Gumbo I tryed to use EditText but it didn't really work it just showed that it editable but didn't gave an option to change things ..

Comment: The thing about StackOverflow is that it is meant for specific questions only, that keeps the conversation objective. If you just ask "how can I do xyz", the answer would either be pages long, because there usually are dozens of ways to do xyz, or not really helpfull. So if you have a very specific problem about how to use EditText, you can ask it here, but this question is not according to the rules and thus people are downvoting you. See [help] for more info.

Comment: @Gumbo I fix the question i hope it's now ok..

Comment: Well, that's better, but what exactly is not working? "not let me change anything" is a vague problem description. What exactly happens when you try to change the EditText? Does the on-screen keyboard not open? Does it immediatly undo the change? And is that all the code you have, or is there some java code behind it too that gives the View some function?

Comment: @Gumbo added the java code, i'm trying to understand how to fix everything together but didn't really worked for me.. after i added the EditText it's showing that it's editable but whern i press on something to type some number nothing happen. i'm trying to do exactly the same as in the android build in timer. but the only option i find that i know to do(begginer) is to add anoter activity for editing.. i need somehow to get input from the user into hour,min,sec. and i know for now the sec going up but after i will understand how can i put my own values i will change it

Comment: Thanks, after you posted the code I directly saw the problem. So remember: Include all the code, errormessages and infos you have, describe exactly what is not working and your questions shall be answered ;)

Comment: @Gumbo I don't know if it's change anything but i added the all code with all the buttons .. what do i need to add the make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very simple: You cast your `EditText` to a `TextView`, thereby loosing the ability to edit it. This doesn't give you an error because `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`. You need to change the line

```
final TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
```

to

```
final EditText timeView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
```

and everything should be working.

Comment: it's let me edit but once i press for example 4 it's delete it and return to 0..it's not deleting the 0 it's just add the number i write.

Comment: right now the watch look like 0:00:00 after i write 4 it's for a sec change to 40:00:00 and go back to 0:00:00 .. and thank you so much for helping me men

Comment: Yes, that happens because the timer runs on while you edit, and sets the text back to the current number of seconds